# Changing object in a ConcurrentBag?

Tags: c#, thread-safety

I read that to modify or mutate an object in a concurrent bag I have to take it out, modify it and then put it back in.

However, I have seen code that does the following:

```
var obj = bag.FirstOrDefault(report => report.id == id);
obj.name = 'Change to something else';
```

where Report is a object type that the bag holds.

Now this seems to work. Is this correct though?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works, but it's not thread-safe. See the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779.aspx):

> All public and protected members of `ConcurrentBag<T>` are thread-safe and may be used concurrently from multiple threads. However, members accessed through one of the interfaces the `ConcurrentBag<T>` implements, including extension methods, are not guaranteed to be thread safe and may need to be synchronized by the caller.

In other words, in order to modify or mutate an object in a concurrent bag **in a thread-safe manner** you have to take it out, modify it and then put it back in.

Comment: this means the update operation is not atomic, then is locking the whole operation is the only way of achieving atomicity ?